# Pattern Matching Redundant

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

How can I make sure the pattern

```
func (2:xs) = expression
```

where 2:xs is a length 2 list doesn't match with the pattern

```
func (2:x:xs) = expression2
```

where 2:x:xs is a length 3 list?

Comment: `2:xs` is a list of length at least 1, not of length 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

End the list pattern with empty brackets:

```
func (2:x:[]) = expression
```

This will ensure `x` is a single element from the list.

Answer (score 7):

Adapt this as needed:

```
func [] = ... -- empty case
func [x] = ... -- length=1 case
func [x,y] = ... -- length=2 case
func (x:y:z:zs) = ... -- length>=3 case
```